# How to find if a user is visiting my site from a mobile phone?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I would like to identify if a user visits my website using a mobile phone device (not Ipad or any tablets) or the opposite, if simply is using a desktop/tablet device.

My goal is to load different style.css because of the non responsiveness of my site.

I know how to make if statements for this in my PHP but I do not know how to do the identification part in PHP. Also, any solutions using javascript are acceptable.

For example, mobile phones I consider

```
Iphone (Safari, Chrome, Firefox)
Android  (Safari, Chrome, Firefox)
Windows Phone (IE mobile)
```

Thank you

Comment: google is a wonderful thing - second item I found after 10 second search https://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/wiki/Mobile_Detect

Comment: Downvoters should tell us why they downvoted. This site is getting worse and worse...

Comment: They down vote because the answer to your question can be found easily

Comment: agreed - didnt down vote you but at least TRY google / searching for the answer - it didnt take me more than 10 seconds to find answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

instead of php and jquery you probably want to explore the option of @media queries in CSS

the following article explains the process of setting them up in your stylesheet
**[Different Stylesheets for Differently Sized Browser Windows](http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/)**

Comment: I am not the one who downvoted you, however I prefer a PHP or JS/jQuery solution

Comment: @Karoumpas Why? Css is the right tool for the job. Is there something in particular you want to do that can't be done with Css?